# Bootstrap fluid grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fluid-layout

This is my first time working with bootstrap I have some conceptual questions about how to manipulate the grid so it behaves on various sized screens.

I have developed this reproducible example to help describe my problem:

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/lib/bootstrap_3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div id="page-content" class="application-body-home">
<h2 id="homepage-title">Campsites</h2>
    <div id="content" class="row">
        <input type="hidden" id="geojson_sites" name="geojson_sites_url" value="/sandbar/surveys/sites_geo_json/" readonly>
        <div id="sandbar-intro" class="col-md-4 item">
            <div class="sectionWideTitle">Introduction</div>
            <div  id='intro-text' class="well full">
            </div>  <!-- end of intro-text section-->
        </div>  <!-- end of sandbar intro section-->
        <div id="sandbar-monitoring" class="col-md-4 item">
          <div class="sectionWideTitle">Campsite Monitoring</div>
            <div id="sites-map-div" class="well full">
                <div id="monitoring-text">
                </div>
                </div>  <!-- end of sites-map-div section-->
        </div>  <!-- end of sandbar monitoring section-->
        <div id="sandbar_data" class="col-md-4 item">
            <div class="sectionWideTitle">Campsite Locations and Historical Photos</div>
            <div id="sandbar_data_links" class="well full">
            </div>  <!--end of sandbar data links section-->
</div>  <!-- End of sandbar data section-->

<div class="col-md-4 item">
            <div class="sectionWideTitle">For Additional Information</div>
            <div class="well half">
                <span>For additional information, please contact</span>
                </div>  <!-- end of well half div-->
                <div class="sectionWideTitle">Terms of Use</div>
            <div class="well half">
                        </div>  <!--End of well half div-->
</div>  <!-- End of col-md-4 item additional info section-->

        <div class="col-md-4 item">
            <div class="sectionWideTitle">References</div>
            <div class="well full">
              <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-body">
                                      </div>    <!--end of calss media body tag-->
                </div>
                </div>
      </div>    <!-- End of References Section-->
            <div class="col-md-4 item">
            <div class="sectionWideTitle">Cooperating Agencies and Academic Institutions</div>
            <div class="well half">
                <div class="media">
                </div>
    <div class="media">
                </div>
                            </div>

        </div>  <!-- End of cooperating agencies section-->
</div>  <!-- end of id content class row section -->
</div>  <!-- end of page content tag -->
    </div> <!--end of contaner fluid section-->
</body>
</html>
```

the ` tag is referring to the bootstrap.min.css file attached to this post.

[bootstrap.min.css](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=3A1E0A1E7E1816D0%21106)

I want at most 3 columns on the largest screen and i would like the boxes to extend to the end of the container (get wider).  Currently it will stretch until the boxes are all in the same row.  After 3 columns are reached i would like to have each box stretch so it will cover the entire width of the container.

Is there a way to control how many columns are?

Is there a way to control the order the boxes collapse on each other (i.e. going from 3 columns to two or going from 2 columns to one)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Bootstrap default classes for media query behavior is what you are looking for :

```
<div id="sandbar-monitoring" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 item col-xs-12">
```

- On large screens, you will have 3 items per row
- On tablets, you will have 2 items per row
- On phones, you will have 1 item per row

Comment: Awesome! thanks.  Is there a way to control the order of the boxes when it is 2 columns?

Comment: You could look at offsetting columns with BS' grid system : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid